# Template vars on Mail::send PrestaShop

Tags: php, api, email, prestashop

I have this code to send an email when a customer is added through Web Service

```
$data = array(
'{firstname}' => (string)$customer->firstname,
'{lastname}' => (string)$customer->lastname,
'{email}' => (string)$utilizador->Email,
'{passwd}' => (string)$utilizador->Password,
'{shop_name}' => 'BikeZone',
'{shop_url}' => 'http://maggpresta.atomsrv.com'
);

$dump = Mail::Send(2, 'account', 'Criação de conta de cliente', $data,
                   $utilizador->Email,   $customer->firstname.' '.$customer->lastname,
                   null, null, null, null,_PS_MAIL_DIR_, true, 1, false);
```

And it's working. The email is sent but the template vars are all empty as you can see in this image.

[image: Prestashop empty template vars]

Did anyone got the same problem? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems time ago with this function, but I found how to use it correctly:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/398911-solucionado-estructura-de-la-funci%C3%B3n-mailsend/

The correct use from $data array should be:

```
$data = array();
$data['{shop_name}'] = Tools::safeOutput(Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME', null, null, null));
$data['{message}'] = $message;
$data['{email}'] = $from;
```